Associating spamd connections with mail IDs?
Local users on our system use procmail to pass their mail through spamd. We use Postfix on Ubuntu 22.04.
The Postfix mail entry first shows the mail ID, eg:
Jul 30 07:54:18 alice postfix/qmgr[235769]: 2C704BA328: from=<SRS0=RLoz=O6=mail.boots.com=bounce@ourdomainhere.com>, size=61699, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

The spamd lines in the log then look like this, but do not mention the ID:
Jul 30 07:54:18 alice spamd[1860392]: spamd: connection from ::1 [::1]:44212 to port 783, fd 5
Jul 30 07:54:18 alice spamd[1860392]: spamd: setuid to slucy succeeded
Jul 30 07:54:18 alice spamd[1860392]: spamd: processing message <NM63EC74D6C01FA8E1Fbootsuk_mid_prod1-Ym91bmNlQG1haWwuYm9vdHMuY29t@mail.boots.com> for sslucy:1832
Jul 30 07:54:20 alice spamd[2047327]: util: setuid: ruid=1832 euid=1832 rgid=1835 1951 egid=1835 1951 
Jul 30 07:54:23 alice spamd[1860392]: spamd: clean message (-3.1/7.8) for slucy:1832 in 5.0 seconds, 61039 bytes.
Jul 30 07:54:23 alice spamd[1860392]: spamd: result: . -3 - DKIMWL_WL_HIGH,DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS,HTML_FONT_LOW_CONTRAST,HTML_MESSAGE,MAILING_LIST_MULTI,MIME_HTML_ONLY,RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE,RCVD_IN_VALIDITY_SAFE,SPF_HELO_NONE,SPF_PASS,T_KAM_HTML_FONT_INVALID scantime=5.0,size=61039,user=sslucy,uid=1832,required_score=7.8,rhost=::1,raddr=::1,rport=44212,mid=<NM63EC74D6C01FA8E1Fbootsuk_mid_prod1-Ym91bmNlQG1haWwuYm9vdHMuY29t@mail.boots.com>,autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no
Jul 30 07:54:23 alice spamd[1734900]: prefork: child states: II

If we search for just the mail ID, we see:
Jul 30 07:54:18 alice postfix/smtpd[2047298]: 2C704BA328: client=r105.mail.boots.com[130.248.198.105]
Jul 30 07:54:18 alice postfix/cleanup[2046192]: 2C704BA328: message-id=<NM63EC74D6C01FA8E1Fbootsuk_mid_prod1-Ym91bmNlQG1haWwuYm9vdHMuY29t@mail.boots.com>
Jul 30 07:54:18 alice opendmarc[411763]: 2C704BA328: SPF(mailfrom): mail.boots.com pass
Jul 30 07:54:18 alice opendmarc[411763]: 2C704BA328: mail.boots.com pass
Jul 30 07:54:18 alice postfix/qmgr[235769]: 2C704BA328: from=<SRS0=RLoz=O6=mail.boots.com=bounce@ourdomainhere.com>, size=61699, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 30 07:54:23 alice postfix/local[2046202]: 2C704BA328: to=<slucy@ourdomainhere.com>, orig_to=<boots@net-guardian.co.uk>, relay=local, delay=5.8, delays=0.74/0/0/5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Jul 30 07:54:23 alice postfix/qmgr[235769]: 2C704BA328: removed

According to the Spamassassin docs, the mid field in the spamd log signifies the mail ID, but that only seems to correspond to the Postfix mail ID in some cases but not all (as far as I can tell).
Is there a way of reliably associating the spamd process with a given Postfix mail ID so we can analyse the entire flow?

These surely seem to line up:
 alice spamd[1860392]: spamd: processing message <NM63EC74D6C01FA8E1Fbootsuk_mid_prod1-Ym91bmNlQG1haWwuYm9vdHMuY29t@mail.boots.com>
postfix/cleanup[2046192]: 2C704BA328: message-id=<NM63EC74D6C01FA8E1Fbootsuk_mid_prod1-Ym91bmNlQG1haWwuYm9vdHMuY29t@mail.boots.com>

I would say that spamd[1860392] can be associated with Postfix's 2C704BA328.
Or do you have any example where this message ID would not be the same?

Ah, I see postfix/cleanup line contains both the Postfix (queue?) ID and the mail-id, and that it runs both before and after the spamd process. These have different queue IDs but the same message-id each time. I was concentrating too hard on tracing the queue ID.
